# Match everything between hyphen and overlap?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find everything between the hyphens with regex?
Array answer for below should be   ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]

```
<script>
myRe= new RegExp ("xxxxxx");
myArray = myRe.exec("-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-");
</script>
```

Also... what happens if there are comma's in the string and they need to be included in the array?

Is this below alright...?

```
["a,a,a","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick and easy solution is to look for word characters in the string:

```
"-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-".match(/[\w]+/g)
```

This will return  `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]`

If you needed to match strings with commas in them as well then you could add a comma to the capture group:

```
// added ',' to [\w,]
"-a,a,a-bbb-ccc-ddd-".match(/[\w,]+/g)
```

This will return `["a,a,a", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]`

This solution won't scale well if you're looking for **anything** to be matched between some '-'s, but if you have a simple use case then I'd say use a simple match like the ones demonstrated above.

**Update**

Since your comment said you need to match anything between '-'s, you can use the following regex:

```
/[^\-]+/g
```

This will match anything that is not a '-' in groups, so:

```
"-a,@$#$a,a-bbb-ccc-ddd-".match(/[^\-]+/g)
```

will return  `["a,@$#$a,a", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]`

Comment: Yes... i need everything between. I think the split might work but I don't think it creates an array?

Comment: I updated my answer. Split creates an array, but it won't work because it'll give you empty strings that match the beginning and end of your test case.

Comment: hmmm... it is working but only matching the first one it finds, non-repetitive